# module 'django.template' has no attribute 'resolve_variable'

Tags: python, django

I am porting an old Django project to Django 3.2.

I have come across this code segment, which causes an exception to be raised. I have looked through the django documentation, but it seems the method has been removed completely - with no comments regarding replacement etc.

Here is the offending code segment:

```
class AddGetNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, new_values):
        self.new_values = new_values

    def render(self, context):
        request = template.resolve_variable('request', context) # <- barfs here ...
        params = request.GET.copy()

        for key, value in self.new_values.items():
            resolved = value.resolve(context)  
            if resolved:
                params[key] = resolved
            elif key in params:
                del params[key]

        return '?%s' % params.urlencode()
```

What is the new method to fetch the request object from a context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `template.Variable` class to create a template variable that then has a `resolve` method for retrieving the value from the context

```
def render(self, context):
    request = template.Variable('request').resolve(context)
    ...
```